# Position of GONE Views

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I have a ScrollView->TableLayout->TableRow

Inside the TableLayout thare are some TableRows visible and some gone. Its because clicking a TableRow, some other rows below it will become VISIBLE.
Its everything ok now, except that the rows that I turned VISIBLE may not appear in the screen because they arent in the scrollview display area.
I wanna display them without the user scroll, so I need to get the row position to do the scroll.
The problem is, the Draw inst immediately, so I cant get the position. I tryed invalidate and postinvalidate but inst working.

What should I do?

EDIT: What I realy want is a way to update positions and sizes of my views.

I found the solution here [(Android) Why won't invalidate() update my buttons immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801877/android-why-wont-invalidate-update-my-buttons-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the newly-visible cells are going to be drawn? If you have, say, the cell immediately above it (which would make sense if you're adding the rows with [addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29)), you can get the bottom position of the cells immediately above your newly-visible cells (with [getChildAt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) then calculating the vertical offset), and then use [scrollTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) (or the sexier [smoothScrollTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29)) to scroll to that position - that should scroll so that the new row is at the top of the screen. Highlighting the new row somehow would also help the user see that this is the new content.

Comment: The new rows are already in a different color. Im just doing setVisible(0). But I know where the rows are been turned visible. The problem is the rows cann have diferent sizes. I think the only way to do this the way I want is to force the app to redraw. Or at least to update positions and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

**if you can calculate** the rowHeight. or the height of each row. then you may be able to calculate the position where the row (view) may appear.

and you can call the

```
scrollView.scrollBy(x, y)
```

or

```
scrollView.scrollTo(x, y)
```

in the scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good aprouch and I doing something like that. But I still have some problems because the row size is diferent. I think the only way to do this the way I want is to force the app to redraw. Or at least to update positions and sizes.

Comment: is it possible to consider list view for your situation.

Comment: The problem is my app is almost done. But Im considering right now. Thanks again